# Django choicefield choices not displaying

Tags: django

Im using a choicefield and setting 2 values - 'students', 'teachers',
but for some reason when the form displays it only shows 'teachers' and not 'students'.

```
class SignUpShortForm(SignUpForm):
    role = forms.ChoiceField(
        choices=[],
        widget=forms.Select(attrs={'class':'form-control'}),
        label='I am a...',
    )
    self.fields['role'].choices = [('Teacher', 'Teacher2')]
```

Comment: There is no way this form can show 'teachers'

Comment: Where do you set `students`?

Answer (score 1):

Please look [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/el/1.10/ref/models/fields/#field-choices) You add to your choices only values without keys. Code might look like this:

```
CHOICES = (
    ('students', 'Students'),
    ('teachers', 'Teachers'),
)

class SignUpShortForm(SignUpForm):
    role = forms.ChoiceField(
        choices=CHOICES,
        widget=forms.Select(attrs={'class':'form-control'}),
        label='I am a...',
    )
```